# Receive Push Notification Twice firebase PHP Script

Tags: php, firebase, curl, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to Firebase Send Push Notification. I'm working on Send Push notification To multiple Users Using PHP Script.

PHP SCRIPT

```
function sendPushNotification($fb_key_array, $title) {

        
        $finalPostArray = array('registration_ids' => $fb_key_array,
            'notification' => array(
                'title' => $title,
                'sound' => 'default',
                'badge' => '1'
            ),
            'priority' => 'high',
        );
        $server_key = env("SERVER_KEY");
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($finalPostArray));  //Post Fields
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: key=' . $server_key));
        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($server_output);
        return $server_output;
        curl_close($ch);

    }
```

I'm send notification using Queue Jobs on Particular Time.
I have a problem when I send Three notification at same time than Notification receive Twice.
Response From This Curl

```
App\Jobs\PushNotification
<pre>{"multicast_id":4668247729883149905,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1616386021446151%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"}]}[2021-03-22 04:07:01][261] Processed:  App\Jobs\PushNotification
[2021-03-22 04:07:01][262] Processing: App\Jobs\PushNotification
<pre>{"multicast_id":4539206321688711164,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1616386022124068%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1616386022123922%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"}]}[2021-03-22 04:07:01][262] Processed:  App\Jobs\PushNotification
[2021-03-22 04:07:02][263] Processing: App\Jobs\PushNotification
<pre>{"multicast_id":1591082090876608595,"success":3,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1616386023195991%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1616386023196003%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1616386023195724%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"}]}[2021-03-22 04:07:02][263] Processed:  App\Jobs\PushNotification
```

And Receive 6 Notification .but I send Only Three Notification. Where is my Fault ?

Help Thank You

Comment: Can you show the code where you call this function? I assume it's in some kind of loop?

Comment: Thanks For Comment, No I'm sure it is not in any loop @Darren

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about that there is nothing wrong with your func but you can try this it's the same but little different if not work so that mean you have a loop somewhere in your code ..

```html
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$fields = array (
        'registration_ids' => $target,
         // fix new json format
        'notification' => array(
            'body' => 'this is firebase test mesging',
            'title' => 'hello from firebase',
            'badge' => 1,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'priority' => 'high',
        )

);

$fields = json_encode($fields);

$server_key = 'ur_server_kay';
// inherited key

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key='.$server_key
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);

if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);
```